# double loop does not match

Tags: r, loops

I'm having trouble with a loop that I'm trying to do.

I have data for monthly temperature (web-scraping from TerraClimate). I have to set the latitude and longitude, and my code gives me one observation for the average temperature of each month.
I have many pairs of coordinates that I need to web scrape so I'm doing a loop. The problem is that I'm trying to paste the name of the location and it's not working.

Here is an example:
I have a list with the coordinates
and an object with the names

```
loc1 <- c(-70.6666667, -33.4500000) 
loc2 <- c(-71.6163889,-33.0458333) 
c=list(loc1,loc2)
x=c("Loc 1", "Loc 2")
```

And my code looks like this:

```
# web scraping temperature data
var <- "tmax"
terra <- paste0(paste0("http://thredds.northwestknowledge.net:8080/thredds/dodsC/agg_terraclimate_",var),"_1958_CurrentYear_GLOBE.nc")
nc <- nc_open(terra)
lon <- ncvar_get(nc, "lon")
lat <- ncvar_get(nc, "lat")

# creating empty object to paste each set of data
DAT <- NULL 

# loop that brings up the temperatures for each set of coordinates in c
  for(i in c){
# names of locations
    for(n in x){
  flon = match(abs(lon -i[1]) < 1/48, 1)
  lonindex = which(flon %in% 1)
  flat = match(abs(lat -i[2]) < 1/48, 1)
  latindex = which(flat %in% 1)
  start <- c(lonindex, latindex, 1)
  count <- c(1, 1, -1)  
  
  data <- as.numeric(ncvar_get(nc, varid = var,start = start, count))
  data <- as.data.table(data)
  data$date <- seq(as.Date("1958-02-01"), length.out=756, by="month")
  data$ym_chr <- format(data$date, format = "%Y-%m")
  data[,date:=NULL]
  data$LOCATION <- as.character(c[n])
  DAT <- rbind(DAT, data)
    }  
  }
```

The problem is that the second part of the loop is not matching how I would like. Each location has 756 observations, so in total I should have 1512 obs. For the first time the loop runs, I would like "Loc 1" to be under LOCATION, and then, the second time the loop runs, for LOCATION to be "Loc 2".
But instead I'm getting 3024 observations.

This is a replicable code.

Comment: You are looping through 2 choices 2 times each, so 4 * 756 = 3024.  You only need one loop.

Comment: I understand... Do you know how can I do it? I've tried with a list but its not working